# Is my blender somehow bugged (lots of useless drop down menus)

Tags: interface

I just updated from 2.82 to latest 2.91. This is what I noticed immediatelly. The modifiers take twice as much space. On the left is 2.82 and on the right is 2.91.
[image]

Is this supposed to be like that or is my version broken in some way? I used my startup file and prefs from 2.82, should I redo my install or is it really supposed to be like that?

Comment: More options: more fun! (and more confusion as well), If you don't need all of the new parameters available to you, in favor of some screen real estate, you can click on the triangles for the parameter to minimize them.

Comment: Maybe because this is an old file all the menus have been expanded automatically?   Just so you know, Apply and Copy are now located under the drop down arrow next to the viewport and render visibility buttons.

Comment: There are only two new options, the shell and the rim vertex groups at the bottom. The rest is pretty much the same. Just with tons of wasted space and a lot more scrolling. To me this looks and feels like a big downgrade. I use modifiers a lot and this adds a lot of unnecessary scrolling for me. I think I'll stay with 2.82 until there is an addon that fixes this.

Comment: If you don't want the new options of the new version, then you probably don't need to upgrade. Work in the old one. No need to be unhappy.

Comment: Well I am unhappy as this makes all future blender versions annoying for me. I'd like to use the latest software so I can have the complete toolset available to me and having to stay back because of these kind of issues is annoying. But in reality I just don't understand how making the menus take more space and hiding stuff under countless dropdown menus is an improvement. No matter how I look it the left side image is better in every imaginable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. I think it is because:
A) The bigger layout is easier to work with, and
B) It's probably easier to code as well. Just stacking the widgets has got to be simpler than the compact format.

Comment: I dislike it a lot. If I have couple of modifiers for an object then the modifier list gets really long and cumbersome to use very quickly. Constant need to scroll and click dropdown menus open to access basic functionality. I don't see how bigger layout with ore wasted space is easier to work with. I think I'll stay with 2.83.

Comment: Does collapsing the modifier GUIs by clicking those little arrows help you any? They little triangles next to the names of every sub-area of the modifier.